# JavaScript New Object by Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to implement polymorphism in Javascript/node.js. I'm trying to do something, but I'm not sure what it's called so I'm not even sure what I'm searching for.

I have a number of different ES6 Classes that are interchangeable and have the same interface. I'm trying to make a system that is extensible and pluginable, so the classes available won't be known at design time.

I want to have a variable which defines the name of the class that I want to create an instance of. So effectively I want to have the following:

```
class Foo { }
class Bar { }

var classToLoad = "Foo";

var myFoo = new classToLoad;   // I want this to be equivalent to new Foo;

var classToLoad = "Bar";
var myBar = new classToLoad;   // I want this to be equivalent to new Bar;
```

Can anyone tell me what the name for this is and how to properly do it?

Comment: You can put them in an object `cls = { Foo: class Foo {}, Bar: class Bar {} }` and do property access `myFoo = new cls[classToLoad]()`

Comment: Is it possible to do that if I don't know what classes may be available at design time? This is meant to be a pluginable system.

Comment: Plug them in by extending the main object. Then make sure that property exists before calling it

Comment: Imagine `var x=1, y=2;  var iNeed="y";  console.log(iNeed);` you want it to print "2"?

Comment: `var myFoo = new (eval(classToLoad));`. But is there a reason you have to use a string? You could simply do `var classToLoad = Foo`, and then `var myFoo = new classToLoad;`

Comment: It's coming from a database. The database says "load plugins x, y, and z", where x, y, and z are the names of the plugin classes.

Comment: Note, that there are no classes in JS, it is just a syntactic sugar for functions. Just make your functions properties of an object, so then you can access them by a string key. You can not get a variable by its string name.

Comment: It seems like the sensible thing to do would be to require plugins to register themselves before you can use them. The registration would associate a string to a class. This would also allow you to provide sensible errors if a user tried to use a non-existent plugin.

Comment: Why don't you `require` the class? I presume the plugins reside in their own files.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that @zeroflagL, because at design time i have no way of knowing what plugins a user might have.

Comment: I don't understand your argument. You would use `require` or `import` **because** you don't know the plugins at build time.

Comment: Don't I need to know a filename to do that though?

Comment: Not at build time.

Answer (score 3):

There should be a container to identify classes by their names. Notice that there may be more than one class of same name, and function/class names are minified in client-side scripts.

```
class Foo { }
class Bar { }

const container = { Foo, Bar };

let classToLoad = "Foo";

let myFoo = new container[classToLoad]();
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help:

```
var Foo = class Foo { }
var Bar = class Bar { }

var classToLoad = "Foo";

var myFoo = new window[classToLoad]();   // I want this to be equivalent to new Foo;

var classToLoad = "Bar";
var myBar = new window[classToLoad]();   // I want this to be equivalent to new Bar;
```

Comment: You need to have `Foo = class Foo { }`  without "var".

Comment: This may work, but I'm not sure it's really achieving what I'm trying to do, which is a create a node.js application to which users can install plugins.

Comment: @IvanKuckir If this code is not inside a function, the variables will be global.

Comment: @DavidFindlay Put the name-to-class mapping in an object, and provide a plug-in registration function that adds to the object.

Comment: @Barman they will be global, but not properties of a Window. They will belong to Window only when not using "var".

Comment: @IvanKuckir There's no such thing as a global that doesn't belong to window (in browser). They are properties of window if they are global.They won't be global when the code isn't evaluated in global scope.

Comment: Does node.js have window?

Comment: @estus `const`, `let` and `class` don't add a property to the global object even when they are evaluated in global scope.

Comment: @zeroflagL That's true. I don't remember the actual term for 'global scope' you're talking about... ah, it's 'global environment record'. Guys above talked about how `var` (yes, this won't work for a class if there's no `var Foo = class Foo` or `Foo = class Foo`). Also this won't work for `var` in Node which seems to be the case here because scripts are evaluated in module scope.

Comment: @estus The actual term for global scope is global scope ;) Or outermost scope. Scope == visibility, environment record == bindings.